# eOSDeviceScan opens ThemeChanger

Tags: steam, hacknet

Running `eOSDeviceScan.exe` on any computer opens the `ThemeChanger.exe` window. Creating a new account, deleting `ThemeChanger`, and renaming `eOSDeviceScan` do nothing. This has been happening since the v4.034 update.

Comment: Have you tried opening ThemeChanger.exe ?

Comment: It opens the `ThemeChanger` window as normal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what the issue is but a few ideas you could try:

1. Delete the `eosDeviceScan.exe` and re-acquire it from the entropy asset server: `166.53.175.195` in the `/bin` folder
2. See what happens in the hacknet command prompt that opens when you launch the game when you attempt to launch `eosDeviceScan.exe`:

   [image: cmdPrompt example]
3. Start a new game - The developers acknolwedged this bug and created a patch for it. Older game saves will still have the bug but I'm not sure when you started the game/when the save was created:

   [image: Dev Message]

[Steam Thread with the same issue](https://steamcommunity.com/app/365450/discussions/0/451850020338010159/#p1)

Comment: is the `eosDeviceScan.exe` also some where else? For me the file on the entropy server is already the `ThemeChanger.exe`... My cat output for `eosDeviceScan.exe` is the following

Comment: `1001001111010101101111001001110110110100110001110001010110110010110101111101000111100110110011010110011111110110000001001001101010110011111101100111111111000000110000110101000100100111100110110000001001010101000100110011011011011000100101000101000101011110100101111101101010110001100000011010111100001011001111011010011011110101111110010010011101110011101101110100100011111110001011000010111100110100101110100100111010100110011101010111100110` is that the correct file?